# Visual Studio 2010 C#: Filter Trace Output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to filter the Output Window in Visual Studio 2010, when writing with Trace.WriteLine to it? For example, I got different trace categories, which I want to filter for.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, two require code and one is a VS 2010 add-in.

1. Use NLog with a DebugTarget to redirect logging to the Output window. You can then log information at different levels, e.g. Trace, Debug, Error, Warn, Info.
2. Write your own `DefaultTraceListener`, read this [article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020910.htm) for some information and search Google for examples.
3. There is an add-in in the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) that may help, I've used it before however I 
   cannot recall the name and a quick search did not turn up any results.

HTH,